# ArrayList doesn't add new "NotiIbjects" when button pressed

Tags: c#, windows, list, arraylist, uwp

So I'm trying to pop out a random notification ever x seconds. I have a function that adds a new instance of the UserControl: "NotiObject" to a stack panel. I try to access each one and put them into a List. Then I get a random "i" from 0 to the max of the List to make a random notification. When I add a object to the StackPanel, it wouldn't get noticed and added to the list. Could anyone see what's wrong? Thanks.

Code:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    int count = 0;
    int i;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        notificationController();

        foreach (NotiObject noti in itemsPanel.Children.Where(c => c is NotiObject))
        {
            notiList.Add(noti);

        }
    }

    private void notificationController()
    {
        i = new Random().Next(0, notiList.Count);
        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler<object>(Timer_Tick);
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        if(notiList != null)
        {
            NotiObject randomNoti = notiList[i];
            randomNoti.sendNotification();
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        itemsPanel.Children.Add(new NotiObject());
    }
```

Comment: Does the following work, and any updates for this thread ?

Answer (score 0):

> ArrayList doesn't add new "NotiIbjects" when button pressed

It's by design, you placed `notiList.Add(noti);` in MainPage's ctor, and this ctor will invoke one time when the page load. So it will not add the new  "NotiIbjects" when button pressed.

For solving this problem, we suggest your call `notiList.Add(noti)`in button click method like following.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var notiobj = new NotiObject();
    itemsPanel.Children.Add(notiobj );
    notiList.Add(notiobj);
}
```